# Returning byte[64] from a function works in TestRPC not in Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, testrpc, evm

I have a smart contract which is returning a byte[64] array. In testrpc I get the correct array but in Geth I am getting array with all "0x".

Here is the smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract DataStore
{
    function stringToBytes32(string memory source) returns (bytes32 result) {
        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }

    function DataStore()
    {
    }

    function str_to_bytes(string str) constant returns (byte[64]){
        bytes memory b = bytes(str);
        byte[64] final_str;
        for(uint i; i<b.length; i++){
            final_str[i] = b[i];
        }

        return final_str;
    }

    function getValue() public returns (byte[64])
    {
        return str_to_bytes("sasdasdasdasdasdasd");
    }
}
```

The output of the `getValue()` function is in-correct in Geth but is correct in TestRPC.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `str_to_bytes` function change `byte[64] final_str;` to `byte[64] memory final_str;` and it works in Quorum too.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that either your Geth node isn't fully synchronised, you are pointing to the wrong address or the contract isn't correctly deployed to the network that Geth is pointing to.

I've deployed the contract to [Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x9fbda871d559710256a2502a2517b794b482db40) and when I call the *getValue* function I see the expected output:

> bytes1[64]: 0x73, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

One comment on the code, I suggest that you modify the *getValue* function to the constant or view to prevent the transaction having to be mined to view the output of the function:

```
function getValue() public view returns (byte[64])
    {
        return str_to_bytes("sasdasdasdasdasdasd");
    }
```

Comment: Actually I am trying it on Geth of Quorum not Vanilla Ethereum. So on quorum I am getting empty bytes.

Comment: At a high-level, Quorum's version of Geth really isn't that different to vanilla Geth - it still exposes exactly the same JSON RPC interface, has mostly the same block structure, works with web3 etc.
I still think that the cause of your issue is something more fundamental.

Comment: I just tried in Vanilla Etherum's Geth and it's working. Still it doesn't work on Quorum's geth.

Comment: can you try it on Quorum?

Comment: In Quorum's console I see this error: `VM returned with error                   err="invalid opcode 0xfd"`